# How do you avoid turning an oxy-acetylene torch off when doing two handed work?

Tags: welding

I'm working on a project that has lots of little pieces to weld together.  After each weld, I need to use both hands to setup the next one.

I'm using oxy-acetylene and I really dislike setting the torch on the table top and hoping it doesn't move.  I've tried searching for a solution, but every query I attempted was saturated with more common questions... I couldn't find the right query.

One thing I did find was a really cheap holder that I would never trust.

How do people work with these torches when there's a lot of two handed assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hook to hang it from is pretty typical. I'll have a look and see if I can find any illustrations of those, but it's quite basic and usually shop-made.

Many are hung off a lever attached to a device (Gas-Saver) that reduces the flame to a pilot-size - at least if the person has enough use for not-relighting and re-adjusting to justify the cost of that item. Back in the day, Sears had that feature (pilot-flame switch) built into their torch handle.

Comment: I'll probably make my own.  Would love to see some inspirational photos if you find the time.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of holders out there. A quick [Amazon search](https://amzn.to/3gjoa66):

[image: Torch holder]

And since you have a torch and know how to use it, you could probably build something yourself. But basically look for:

- Metal for safety
- Make sure it is sized to fit your torch
- Heavy base or strong well-spaced legs for stability

Comment: Yeah, just make sure that wherever you set that doesn't have something flammable or meltable at the business end.

Comment: This was the one I found that seemed a bit iffy to me.  I don't feel like having unnecessary hot spots on the table, and there's no guards.  Perhaps something that shoots forward with a bit of shielding can be built.

Comment: That was the first one I found that looked like a possibility. But I agree, something more substantial or with a guard/shielding makes sense. There are a *lot* of options out there.